# How to create a grails plugin that provides assets to the main project

Tags: grails, plugins

I want to create a grails plugin that will have assests that can be used in the projects it's used

Assets: JS, CSS and Images

Comment: Please expand on what you mean by "assets"... Are you referring to the general definition or components of the new asset pipeline? Please provide some examples.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, then have at it. The [Twitter bootstrap plugin](https://github.com/groovydev/twitter-bootstrap-grails-plugin) does this and you could use it as a guide on how to do so.